# How can I show that if $A = A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_k$, where $A_1, \dots ,A_k$ are disjoint, then we know the sum of all elements in $A$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

If I have that $A = A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_k$, where $A_1, \dots ,A_k$ are disjoint, and that $N(A_i) = $ number of elements in $A_i$, how can I show that

$P(N(A_1) = a_1, \dots , N(A_k) = a_k \mid \sum_{i=1}^{k}N(a_i) = n) = P(N(A_1) = a_1, \dots , N(A_k) = a_k)$?

In other words, how can I show that if I have that $A = A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_k$, where $A_1, \dots ,A_k$ are disjoint, then knowing $N(A_1) = a_1, \dots , N(A_k) = a_k$ means I already know $\sum_{i=1}^{k}N(a_i) = n$, and so these events are independent of each other? Thanks!

Comment: This is utter nonsense--you are considering events $B=(N(A_1) = a_1, \dots , N(A_k) = a_k)$ and $C=(N(A_1)+\cdots+N(A_k) = n)$. If $n=a_1+\cdots+a_k\ne n$, then $P(B\mid C)=0$. But, and I guess this is your question, if $n=a_1+\cdots+a_k=n$, then $B\subseteq C$ hence $$P(B\mid C)=\frac{P(B)}{P(C)}\ne P(B).$$

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because of the fact $(\cup_{i=1, i\neq j}^{k} A_i)\cap A_j=\phi $